# Prediction of Multiple Linear Regression With Constant

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, svd, matrix-decomposition

Let $X$ be a matrix with $n$ rows and $d$ columns. We know that there exists matrices $U, S, V$, with $U$ of dimensions $(n, d)$, $S$ of dimensions $(d, d)$ and $V$ of dimensions $(d, d)$, which form the singular value decomposition of $X$, such that:

1. $X = USV$
2. $S$ is a diagonal matrix. Assume for this problem that S has full rank.
3. $U^T U = V^TV = VV^T = I_d$.

We also know the formula for multiple linear regression, if we use a response variable $Y$ of $n$ rows and 1 column: $\widehat{\beta} = (X^T\cdot X)^{-1}X^T Y$.

Further, we know the formula for the prediction from this linear regression: $X\widehat{\beta} = X\cdot (X^T\cdot X)^{-1}X^T Y$.

This formula can be rewritten in terms of $U, S, V$: $X\widehat{\beta} = U\cdot U^TY$.

My question is the following:

Say that I want to run a very similar regression, but now, I am trying to predict Y by using a new matrix $X'$, which has the same observations as $X$ except it also has a new column, which is made entirely of 1s. From this regression we obtain a new vector of coefficients, and let's call it $\widehat{\beta}'$.

Is there a formula expressing this new prediction, $ X'\widehat{\beta}'$ in terms of the original values U, S, V from the SVD decomposition of X? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Should we take it that your first regression lacks an intercept or other characteristics that would lead to perfect multicollinearity with the added column of $1$s?

Comment: My first regression lacks an intercept. The motivation for my question is the following: I am trying to interpret and understand the F-statistic in multiple linear regression. My understanding is that the F statistic is $\frac{\sum (\widehat{y_i} - \overline{y})^2}{\sum (\widehat{y_i} - y_i)^2} \cdot$  $\frac{n-p-1}{p}$, but I don't understand the following: 1. What regression does the $\widehat Y$ come from? 2. What exactly is the null hypothesis? Is it that $ y = \mu + x^T\beta + \sigma^2 \epsilon$, where $ \beta$ is actually a vector of zeros and the epsilons are iid Gaussians with mean 0?